# What is a round closing bracket in a script tag?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url, reference

I am learning MVC4 by reading through [Professional ASP.NET MVC4](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-4.productCd-111834846X.html), I came across this:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery_script.js")
    ></script>
```

I have never seen a bracket without an opening like this, do anyone knows anything about this?

Comment: It looks like a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be an invalid script tag, it's probably just a typo, an editing error, or (as you say it's in a book and in a lot of places) some kind of rendering or transformation error. Books are frequently written in one source format and converted to various others, it's probably some error in the conversion for the version you're reading.

If it were a real script tag, the browser would probably succeed in understanding it, but just remove the `)` and close things up. (The reason it's "invalid" is it defines an attribute called `)` with no value, and `script` elements aren't defined to have an attribute called `)`.)

Comment: Maybe it's a typo but it's at many places in the book. How 4 top level expert authors can make these many mistakes?

Comment: @student: I've updated the answer. Probably a rendering or transformation error then.